# Lightning component lazy loading as lightning:tabset

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a bunch of components `<c:CmpA />`, `<c:CmpB />` ...

Sometimes, I need to perform a check for access rights to this component, so I decided to create a `<c:CheckWrapper></c:CheckWrapper>` as this:

```
<aura:component description="CheckWrapper"
                controller="CheckWrapperController"
>
  <aura:if isTrue="{! not(v.loading) }">

    <aura:if isTrue="{! v.isAllowed }">
    {! v.body }
      <aura:set attribute="else">
        {! v.error }
      </aura:set>
    </aura:if>

  </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Its JS controller perform a check on Apex, and then release `v.isLoading` and `v.isAllowed` (or not).

The usage is has this:

```
<c:CheckWrapper somethingToCheck="['this', 'that']">
  <c:CmpA attr="{! v.attr }" />
</c:CheckWrapper>
```

Everything works perfectly **except that** even if you are not allowed to use this component (and it will not be mounted on the DOM because of `<aura:if isTrue="{! v.isAllowed }">`), it is instantiate and its `<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>` is performed.

How can I prevent this without dynamically creating the component ? As an example, `<lightning:Tab>` and `<lightning:Tabset>` work exactly the same way but the child component's init handler is performed on render.

```
<lightning:tabset selectedTabId="{! v.stepName }" >
  <lightning:tab label="label" aura:id="id" id="id" >
      <c:CmpA attr="{! v.attr }" />
      <!-- Tab is loaded, component is mounted, init is performed -->
  </lightning:tab>
  <lightning:tab label="label2" aura:id="id2" id="id2" >
      <c:Cmpb attr="{! v.attr }" />
      <!-- Tab is hidden, component is unmounted, init is not performed until open the tab -->
  </lightning:tab>
</lightning:tabset>
```

Do you have any idea I can have the same behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this** inside your CheckWrapper Component.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! v.isAllowed }">
    <c:CmpA attr="{! v.attr }" />
    {! v.body }
    <aura:set attribute="else">
    {! v.error }
</aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

**Edit Solution 2:**

Here you can pass your component as an attribute to checkWrapper and let checkWrapper decide whether to show or not components.

Test App Code

```
<aura:application >
    <c:CheckWrapper componentName="c:CmpA"></c:CheckWrapper>
</aura:application>
```

CheckWrapper.cmp

```
<aura:component description="CheckWrapper" controller="CheckWrapperController">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.isAllowed}" action="{!c.isAllowedChanged}" />

<aura:attribute name="somethingToCheck" type="String"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="componentName" type="String"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="component_attributes" type="String"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="isAllowed" type="Boolean" default="false"></aura:attribute>

<aura:if isTrue="{! not(v.loading) }">

<aura:if isTrue="{! v.isAllowed }">
        {! v.body }

        <aura:set attribute="else">
        {! v.error }
      </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

CheckWrapperController.js

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var show = component.get("v.isAllowed");
    if(show)
    helper.createCmp(component,event);

},
isAllowedChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
    var show = component.get("v.isAllowed");
    if(show)
    helper.createCmp(component,event);
}
```

CheckWrapperHelper.js

```
createCmp : function(component,event) {

    var cmpName= component.get("v.componentName");
    var cmpAttr = component.get("v.component_attributes");
    var cmp = component;
    $A.createComponent(cmpName, cmpAttr, function(newComp, status, errorMessage){

            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(newComp);
                cmp.set("v.body", body);
            }

        });
}
```

CmpAController.js

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('comp A initiated');
}
```

CmpA.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <h1>I'm Component A</h1>
</aura:component>
```

You can change the default value of isAllowed to true on checkWrapper to check component creation. 
Hope this helps!!

Comment: This works but the purpose is to not specify component inside the checkWrapper so it can be used for every component that requires a check

Comment: About your edit: this is a really good idea and it could work where the attribute binding is not used but I need to be able to do `<c:CmpA attr="{! v.valueThatCouldChange }>`

Comment: I think it should work fine. Make a Parent Component and CheckWrapper as child component. As the components are nested inside checkWrapper they should be binded to any attribute present on parent component

Comment: i'll try to see if i could improve it. @SimonPlacentino

Answer (score 0):

So, I followed the (perfect) answer of [pranav prashant](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/210908/37707) but I am facing a new issue. First, here is the entire implementation I have.

Markup:

```
<aura:component description="CheckWrapper"
                controller="CheckWrapperController"
>

  <aura:attribute name="isAllowed"    type="Boolean" access="private" default="{! false }" />
  <aura:attribute name="loading"      type="Boolean" access="private" default="{! true }" />

  <aura:attribute name="error"        type="Aura.Component[]" access="public"/>

  <aura:attribute name="bodyAttributes"     type="Map"     />
  <aura:attribute name="bodyDefinition"     type="String" required="{! true }" />
  <aura:attribute name="bodyContent"        type="Aura.Component[]" access="private"/>

  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

  <aura:if isTrue="{! not(v.loading) }">

    <aura:if isTrue="{! v.isAllowed }">
    {! v.bodyContent }
      <aura:set attribute="else">
        {! v.error }
      </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
  </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Controller + Helper:

```
({
  doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.checkAccess(component);
  }

})

({
  checkAccess: function(component) {
    const action = component.get('c.hasAccess');
    action.setCallback(this, response => {
      // if success
        component.set('v.isAllowed', allowed);

        if(allowed) {
          this.createComponent(
            component,
            component.get('v.bodyDefinition'),
            component.get('v.bodyAttributes') || {}
          );
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },

  createComponent: function(component, bodyDefinition, bodyAttributes) {
    $A.createComponent(bodyDefinition, bodyAttributes, (body, status, errorMessage) => {
      if (status === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set('v.bodyContent', body);
      } else {
        console.error(errorMessage);
      }

      component.set('v.loading', false);
    });

  }
})
```

Then I create a `*WithPermission` wrapper where it is required.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable"
                description="CmpAWithPermission"
                access="global"
>

  <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:CmpA" />
  <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:CheckWrapper" />

  <c:CheckWrapper bodyDefinition="c:CmpA">
    <aura:set attribute="error">
      <p>Woups</p>
    </aura:set>
  </c:CheckWrapper>
</aura:component>
```

In case where wrapped component needs some attributes, I add to my `*WithPermission` component an attribute as this:

```
  <aura:component description="CmpBWithPermission"
                  access="public"
                  implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">

    <aura:attribute name="cmpBAttributes"     type="Map"  />

    <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:CmpB"   type="COMPONENT" />

    <aura:handler name="init"
                  value="{!this}"
                  action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <c:CheckWrapper bodyDefinition="c:CmpB" bodyAttributes="{! v.cmpBAttributes}"/>

</aura:component>
```

With controller:

```
({
  doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

    component.set('v.cmpBAttributes', {
      recordId: component.get('v.recordId') // for exemple
    });
  }
})
```

But now the **new issue I am facing** is when one of this `*WithPermission` component is used as a tab content (setup -> search(tab) -> Lightning Component Tab), when I switch to another tab and come back to te previous one, my component exist multiple time on the page:

```
<article class="slds-card cCheckWrapper" data-aura-rendered-by="50:1530;a" data-aura-class="cCheckWrapper">
<!-- The last one, content OK -->
</article>
<article class="slds-card cCheckWrapper" data-aura-rendered-by="50:1530;a" data-aura-class="cCheckWrapper">
<!-- The second time I browse the component, empty: NOK -->
</article>
<article class="slds-card cCheckWrapper" data-aura-rendered-by="50:1530;a" data-aura-class="cCheckWrapper">
<!-- The first time I browse the component, empty: NOK -->
</article>
```

I do not get why because the component, even dynamic, is autoDestroyed because assigned to `Aura.Component[]` type (as described in the documentation).

Comment: Problem solved, `CmpA` was like `<p>...</p><lightning:card title=""></lightning:card>` then only `<p>` was deleted. I wrapped everything together